# Hangfire error, recurring job is unable to execute

Tags: hangfire

I have used the following attributed on the Job:

```
[SkipWhenPreviousJobIsRunning]
[DisableConcurrentExecution(180)]
[Queue("{0}")]
```

Following is the code for ***SkipWhenPreviousJobIsRunning attribute***

```
public class SkipWhenPreviousJobIsRunningAttribute: JobFilterAttribute, IClientFilter, IApplyStateFilter
{
    public void OnCreating(CreatingContext context)
    {
        var connection = context.Connection as JobStorageConnection;

        // We can't handle old storages
        if (connection == null) return;

        // We should run this filter only for background jobs based on 
        // recurring ones
        if (!context.Parameters.ContainsKey("RecurringJobId")) return;

        var recurringJobId = context.Parameters["RecurringJobId"] as string;

        // RecurringJobId is malformed. This should not happen, but anyway.
        if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(recurringJobId)) return;

        var running = connection.GetValueFromHash($"recurring-job:{recurringJobId}", "Running");
        if ("yes".Equals(running, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase))
        {
            context.Canceled = true;
        }
    }

    public void OnCreated(CreatedContext filterContext)
    {
    }

    public void OnStateApplied(ApplyStateContext context, IWriteOnlyTransaction transaction)
    {
        if (context.NewState is EnqueuedState)
        {
            var recurringJobId = SerializationHelper.Deserialize<string>(context.Connection.GetJobParameter(context.BackgroundJob.Id, "RecurringJobId"));
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(recurringJobId)) return;

            transaction.SetRangeInHash(
                $"recurring-job:{recurringJobId}",
                new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Running", "yes") });
        }
        else if (context.NewState.IsFinal /* || context.NewState is FailedState*/)
        {
            var recurringJobId = SerializationHelper.Deserialize<string>(context.Connection.GetJobParameter(context.BackgroundJob.Id, "RecurringJobId"));
            if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(recurringJobId)) return;

            transaction.SetRangeInHash(
                $"recurring-job:{recurringJobId}",
                new[] { new KeyValuePair<string, string>("Running", "no") });
        }
    }

    public void OnStateUnapplied(ApplyStateContext context, IWriteOnlyTransaction transaction)
    {
    }
}
```

**During the development locally, it is working fine but getting error after deployment with the following errors in the Dashboard:**

```
System.FormatException: Index (zero based) must be greater than or equal to zero and less than the size of the argument list.
   at System.Text.ValueStringBuilder.AppendFormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.FormatHelper(IFormatProvider provider, String format, ParamsArray args)
   at System.String.Format(IFormatProvider provider, String format, Object[] args)
   at Hangfire.QueueAttribute.OnStateElection(ElectStateContext context)
   at Hangfire.States.StateMachine.InvokeOnStateElection(Tuple`2 x)
```

Kindly provide some help on this

Comment: I found the issue, it is due to `[Queue("{0}")]`
As, the exception stated that issue is on the **QueueAttribute**. We are calling the Job without Queue name.